# Horizontally align image and header title (div), and add width to hr (NO TABLE)

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to align my logo with my header title and subtitle.

I've attempted to do this using `display: inline-block`. I didn't manage to,
and I also attempted with floats, but everything messed up.

I've then put a hr (line) under the header, but it's too thin, so I want to add thickness to it, but I can't manage to.

I've looked up this question but couldn't use answers to help me as most of them used tables.

How can do this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjmMdM

[image: What I'm looking for]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <header>
                <img class="logo" src="hidden.jpg" alt="Logo">

                <div id="title">
                    <h1>Lorem Epsum</h1>
                    <h3>Front Ninja</h3>
                </div>
            </header>

            <hr id="line">

            <section>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### File style.css

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

header {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    border: #F8981C solid 5px;
    border-radius: 99px;
}

#title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#line {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Since this is a styling question. Please post the relevant css relating to this html.

Comment: Done, as you can see everythings gone horribly wrong so far. Here's a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjmMdM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. I think the issue is that you needed vertical alignments. You have all of the html markup you need. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help you out. Let me know if this is what you're looking for. There are a couple of ways to position the elements; I just added hard left margins to achieve the effect in your wireframe.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/legendarylionwebdesign/b570pyo9/

```
hr {
    border: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#title {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the title, you can just change it like this:

```
#title {
    margin-right: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
```

And play with top or put width and so on [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXzOEp).